# Confuse about Relogin in Twitter4j Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

Right now i develop simple app that require login to my app (not login twitter), and he/she can look our collection and can share it into twitter. In setting there is option to login twitter and i use Twitter4j with [this tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/). My problem is :

1. if Person A login into my App and login Twitter and share content and then Logout my App without logout the Twitter
2. how can i detect if Person B login into my App and want to login Twitter (using same device with Person A) ??
   do i have disconect twitter Person A and than connect Person B ??
3. If I disconect twitter Person A, and maybe Person A login again to my App , i dont want he/she do login Twitter again, i want automaticly..how can do that with twitter4j??

sorry i my qustion hard to understand, my english is bad ><

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to understand but I shall try my best!

Note, this is just an example, there are many ways, better and worse than what I am suggesting so learn, research and good luck!

Now, to do what you're asking for build your application along these steps:

- Create a collection of your preference that accepts some ID and access token object and save the collection permanently via a method of your choice, for use every time the application starts.
- When a Person logs into your app and then twitter, save that Persons access token for twitter with that Person as its ID into your collection.
- Re-save your updated collection.
- Next time a Person logs in, simply check to see if they exist within the collection:
- If they do? Go ahead and auth them with the access token stored.
- If they do not? Go ahead and fire up a new twitter auth process when they need twitter services.

This way no matter how many users use your app on that same device, each twitter access token will be saved and only accessible by the appropriate user.

Also, As far as I am aware, to "log out" of twitter is as simple as deleting/throwing away the access token object relevant to the user wanting to log out.

Hope this helps.